Is it appropriate to calculate odds ratios from random effects glmm output?
Is it appropriate to calculate odds ratios from random effects glmm output?

about the data:

grown (binary): whether flower grows over a certain height (TRUE/FALSE)
fertilizer(factor): whether fertilizer was used (yes, no, unknown)
flowertype (factor): 5 types of flowers


Here's my code:
model <- glmmTMB(grown ~ fertilizer+ (1 + fertilizer | flowertype),
                 data = flower_data, family = "binomial")
random_effects <- as.data.frame(ranef(model))
flower_types <- unique(random_effects$grp)
parameter_type <- unique(random_effects$term)
odds_ratios <- data.frame(flowertype = flower_types,
                 ParameterType = parameter_type,
                 OddsRatio = exp(random_effects$condval))

My code works, I just want to make sure that I'm doing the right thing

You might try broom.mixed::tidy(model, effects = "ran_vals") |> transform(estimate = exp(estimate)) ?
